# How to set up membership-only downloads

Tags: wordpress, civimember, woocommerce

So I want the following to happen:
1. web visitor registers for membership
2. after registering the member would have to "add a pdf to cart" and "check out"

Is there a way on CiviCRM to set something like this up? I am trying to find something, but cannot find anything on having products (a pdf) download available for members to download after registration.

Not sure if CiviContribute, CiviEvent, or CiviCase would be appropriate.

Wordpress is what is being used.

The functionality is basically someone clicks to get a PDF or ebook, and then it takes them to a page where they have to register or donate. In receipt of the donation or registration they would receive the ebook/pdf to download on their computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  I've done something very similar on Drupal but not Wordpress, but there are two different answers depending on your situation:

- If membership entitles someone to download any/all publications, then the easiest approach would be to use [CiviCRM WP Member Sync](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-member-sync/) in conjunction with [Groups](https://wordpress.org/plugins/groups/).  Make your download pages available only to a Wordpress user role called "Members".  Use Civi-WP Member Sync to make any CiviCRM contacts with an active membership also have the "Member" user role.  And of course, enable signing up for a Wordpress account in the membership signup profile.
- If you must pay an additional fee for each publication on top of membership, you'll want to do the above, but also add [WooCommerce](https://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) or another Wordpress e-commerce module.  This is significantly more setup, but if you make your commerce pages available only to members using the approach outlined above, you'll have very fine-grained control.

Answer (score 3):

What CMS are you using? There are product and shopping cart solutions for all three of Drupal, Wordpress, and Joomla.

You also might be able to sort of fake it with premiums on a contribution page so you could toy around with that, but it wouldn't be the shopping cart specification you asked about.

Comment: Wordpress. 

So if someone wants to download a PDF that this business offers, it would take them to a page where they have to either donate or register in order to get the product.

How would you suggest setting it up?

Comment: Check out what @Jon G has to say. It is more setup but it's the right way to do it, especially if there is any chance you will expand to add more product options to this feature or need flexibility in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you find a service (or wordpress plugin) that provides the download service and add a link to that service in the Thank You email for the transaction (donation/membership/etc). Be sure to make the cost of the download be FREE or $0.00. I would not put a direct link to a pdf in the Thank You email because then the buyer can share it.